# Problem with checking for Valid Geometries for PostGIS

Tags: azure, postgis

I have used this PostGIS in different environments many times without issue:

```
update my_table set geom = ST_MakeValid(geom) where ST_IsValid(geom) = false;
```

However in Azure I keep seeing the following response:

```
ERROR:  GEOS isvalid() threw an error!
```

This is using **PostGIS 2.3.2 r15302** and GEOS **3.6.1-CAPI-1.10.1 r4317**

In case it was because geom was null I tried the following:

```
update my_table set geom = ST_MakeValid(geom) 
where geom is not null and ST_IsValid(geom) = false;
```

However I get the same error.

The above was in psql.  I tried DBeaver as well (I have given up on PgAdmin4) and there I see the following slightly different output:

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: GEOS isvalid() threw an error!
```

Googling *GEOS threw an error* seems to point to invalid geometries and suggests the user use ST_IsValid() but in this case that is the function causing the issue.

How do I fix the issue when ST_IsValid() itself throws an error?

Update:

Through searching through hundreds of thousands of entries in the table, I found two with errors.

If I try

```
update my_table set geom = ST_MakeValid(geom) where id in (1234, 5678)
```

then I see the following error

```
ERROR: GEOSisValid(): IllegalArgumentException: Exponent out of bounds
```

How do I fix either error?

Comment: could you post the WKB geometries of those two entries?

Comment: And the OS version? Lots of people run Linux on Azure.

Comment: @ThingumaBob: This is one of them: SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((6.625539714341757E10 2.121995794E-314,-79.4405401677212 -8.483985467320476E12,4.2439915834E-314 8.487983176E-314,6.625539714341757E10 2.121995794E-314)),((-79.44054016772121 43.709715347456374,-79.4405401677212 43.70971534745637,-79.44054016772121 43.70971534745637,-79.44054016772121 43.709715347456374)))

Comment: @JohnPowell It is a managed instance of PostgreSQL in Azure so I do not know the OS version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am still not sure how/why the geometry has an issue, or why the GEOS functions are throwing errors, but I figured out how to clean up the bad data.

Given that both `ST_IsValid()` and `ST_MakeValid()` did not work, I cleaned the geometry as follows:

- Convert it to GeoJSON with `ST_AsGeoJSON()`
- Convert it back to a geometry with `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()`
- At this point it is still invalid, but `ST_IsValid()` works
- Because it is invalid use `ST_MakeValid()`
- Set the SRID back to the desired one with `ST_SetSRID()`

Which results in

```
update my_table 
set geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeValid(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(ST_AsGeoJSON(geom))), 4326)
where id in (1234, 5678)
```

The resulting geometry is valid.